# In Javascript, what is the effect of '>>> 0' on a variable?

Tags: javascript

I am reading an implementation of `Array.prototype.some` on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

It contains this intruiging piece of code:

```
var t = Object(this);
var len = t.length >>> 0;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
```

Why is it calling `len = t.length >>> 0` instead of `len = t.length`?

What difference does `>>> 0` make?

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.7.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

performs a logical (unsigned) right-shift of 0 bits, which is equivalent to a no-op. However, before the right shift, it must convert the x to an unsigned 32-bit integer. Therefore, the overall effect of x >>> 0 is convert x into a 32-bit unsigned integer.

Comment: +1. To directly address OP's question of why not use `t.length`: this is a nice way to ensure that `len` ends up as an integer, regardless of what value (if any) is stored in the `length` property of the object.